# How do I use ninject to inject a session object property?

Tags: c#, ninject

I have a service object that does some work on a particular patient.

```
public class PatientDxService
{
    public Patient Patient { get; set; }

    public PatientDxService(Patient patient)
    {
        this.Patient = patient;
    }
}
```

My service takes in a Patient object as shown above.

I have a `SessionManager` object that has a property to get the session Patient. I want to inject the patient.

```
Bind<PatientDxService>().ToConstructor(x => new PatientDxService(x.Inject<ISessionManager>().Patient));

Bind<ISessionManager>().To<SessionManager>().InSingletonScope();
```

The above does not work for me. I don't really want to inject `ISessionManager` because if I wanted to use the services outside of the web scope, it wouldn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inject the ISessionManager into your Service instead of the Patient. then in constructor (or better yet, where you actually use the Patient), request the Patient from the session.

```
public class PatientDxService
{
    private readonly ISessionManager _session;

    public PatientDxService(ISessionManager session)
    {
        this._session = session;
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        var patient = _session.GetPatient();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid the session dependency to make the service reusable outside of the web scope without having to change it. Maybe my entire approach is wrong.

Comment: in that case you could wrapper `ISessionManager` with a more abstract facade, such as `IPersonAccessor` which only has the `GetPatient()` method. that way whomever uses the service can define how patients are accessed.

Comment: generally I try to adhere to the concept of injecting services, not models. if a class needs a model, inject the service that can provide it.

Comment: Ok, great. I see what you're saying.